# How to "store" latitude and longitude in Android?

Tags: android, gps, storage

I'm building an app to "store" the latitude and longitude in Android. I've been through various posts as to how to retrieve location using Location Manager. But I couldn't really figure out how to store the latitude and longitude on the device or on the server.

Following is the screenshot of the app-activity which is one of the several screens in this survey app.

[image]

So, when/after I enter the address (full address with city/district name) in the edittext field, I call the Location Manager. But how do I store the retrieved latitude and longitude in the provided edittext fields?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you asking? How to get the value from the edittext field or how to put the value inside a field or how to put it to sd or how to send it over the internet? PLEASE MORE SPECIFIC!

Answer (score 1):

After retrieving latitute/longitude from the location manager, you can set the values inside the EditText by using `setText()` method.

```
txtLatitude.setText(strLatitude);
txtLongitude.setText(strLongitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using getText() on the textfield you can get the field into a variable from the textfield. Here's a great example:
[Get Value of a Edit Text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531396/get-value-of-a-edit-text-field)

```
myTextField.getText().toString();
```

If you want to store it on a server you need to create a connection to a server Service or to a server script that will insert the data for you in a database. If you wish to store it locally you can use the local SQLLite server.

Here is some more info about working with the local SQL database:
[How to bookmark a webpage in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501605/how-to-bookmark-a-webpage-in-an-android-application/8501779#8501779)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've read articles on how to store any values in local SQLite or store the values on a server. Will try these solutions and let you know in few days. I'm actually still learning java.

Comment: Cool, I hope you enjoy learning Java. It's a very nice language :D. Here are some great tutorials on Java if you wish to get to know more, they also have some great Android tutorials: http://www.wibit.net/curriculum/courses/programming_java